# ASP.NET HTTP Connection Limit

Tags: asp.net

I know this was required in ASP.NET 1.1 because it would limit http connections to 2 by default.

```
<system.net>
  <connectionManagement>
     <add address="*" maxconnection="8"/>
  </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

However I believe in the 2.0 framework it defaults to 12n where n is the number of cpus?

Can anyone confirm that is correct?

Comment: Did you really need only a yes without any explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the default is 12 * #CPUs (12n) in ASP.NET 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article [ASP.NET 2.0 Performance Guidelines - Threading](http://www.guidanceshare.com/wiki/ASP.NET_2.0_Performance_Guidelines_-_Threading)

What Microsoft says: "The recommendation to limit the number of ASP.NET requests to 12 per CPU is a little arbitrary. However, this limit has proved to work well for most applications."