# Concurrently downloading JSON data from remote service(s)

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, json, optimization

I am pulling JSON data from several remote servers concurrently over HTTP, using a WCF service on both the client and server endpoints. I'm noticing that for each successive request that starts asynchronously the length of time that http request takes is generally increasing, even if the amount of data is not necessarily increasing. In other words if I start 12 thread pool threads (using Func<>.BeginInvoke) then each request, after being timed, is showing up in my logs as such:

```
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 325ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 27437ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 28642ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 28496ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 32544ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 38073ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 41231ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 47914ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 45570ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 61602ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 53567ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 79081ms
```

The process is pretty simple. I am simply starting each request in a loop and then calling .WaitAll() on all of the operations before using the consolidated data.

It looks like the Http requests are taking way longer than they should even with small amounts of data. In fact the difference between small and large amounts of data appears minimal overall. Would this sort of bottleneck be due to concurrent http requests having to share bandwidth, or is there a threading / context-switching issue possible here? Just looking to be pointed in the right direction.

**EDIT** -- Just for clarity, I ran the same process **synchronously** and here are the results:

```
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 20627ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 16288ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 2273ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 4578ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 1920ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 564ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 1210ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 274ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 145ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 21447ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 27001ms
  :HttpRequest invoked. Elapsed: 1957ms
```

The total time (because its synchronous) went up, however you can see clearly that each individual request is generally faster. Unfortunately I dont know of any way to isolate the problem -- but my guess is that its a bandwidth sharing issue between the threads.

So I some more straightforward question I have is:

1) If I use a non-threadpool thread, would this improve

2) Should I group the operations into only a few threads, rather than each request having its own?

3) Is this a standard problem when trying to concurrently download data over Http?

Comment: I am actually also dealing with somewhat of the same issue with multiple concurrent httpRequests. If I send out 50 requests all at the same time, the first one comes back in 300 ms, and the last one comes back after 2000 ms. Your results seem to be indicating there's something else going on. In your synchronous test, the first request came back after 20s?! Maybe this is more of a problem on the server side, what kind of service is this calling?

Comment: @Mike Richard, see my link in the answer I posted, it should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer to this question I ultimately came up with came from this link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/11/why-are-wcf-responses-slow-and-setminthreads-does-not-work.aspx

Which applies if you are calling the same servive method repeatedly.

By tweaking ThreadPool.SetMinThreads() on both client and server I was able to get improved results.

However there are still alot of slowness issues with WCF and transferring over HTTP that I haven't really gotten to the bottom of.

Answer (score 2):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368471/asp-net-http-connection-limit) question there is a setting which controls how many simultaneous HTTP requests can be made. Also, you should be using the BeginGetResponse method on HttpWebRequest for concurrent downloading because it is less expensive than creating threads. Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/DownloadDemo.aspx) for examples.

Comment: Thanks. Is the simultaneous HTTP request setting meant for the server or the client, or both? Also, I am actually using ChannelFactory<T> to call the WCF service, calling the method by name off the service contract.

Comment: The setting should be changed on the application that is performing the download.

Comment: Would that configuration setting only apply if I used HttpWebRequest, or should it work with a WCF ChannelFactory<T> call too? I might have to research if there is an equivalent setting for Wcf clients..

Comment: It should apply for ChannelFactory as well.

Answer (score 2):

Might be related to the concurrency mode of your service. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx and make sure that the service is not single threaded.

Comment: This doesnt seem to help. I think this is a threading issue on the client actually, not sure though.

Comment: The ThreadPool is going to manage the number of threads on its own - there's not much guarantee that you'll have 12 concurrently running threads unless you tweak the SetMaxThreads / SetMinThreads. 2nd, I'd look into what is the service (server side) actually doing - maybe there's some sort of lock contention (like DB accesss / write access to the same file, etc...)

Comment: Would you say that this behavior is expected though, given that on the client, a bunch of concurrent downloads will have to share bandwidth? Meaning if I'm hitting 900kb/s when doing a single download, I might lose speed for each concurrent download I add on top of that. If that is the case I'd think theres little I can do.

Comment: For sure - I don't know what your bandwidth cap is but 900KBs (I guess that you mean kilo bytes per sec, not bits, right?) is pretty high already. If your 12 threads are sharing that bandwidth (with no extra bandwidth available), things will slow down by a factor of 12.